# Determine if a binary tree is subtree of another binary tree using pre-order and in-order strings

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I want to find out whether binary tree T2 is a subtree of of binary tree T1. I read that **one could build string representations for T2 and T1 using pre-order and in-order traversals, and if T2 strings are substrings of T1 strings, T2 is a subtree of T1.**

I am a bit confused by this method and not sure about its correctness.

From wiki: "A subtree of a tree T is a tree consisting of a node in T and all of its descendants in T."

In the following example:

```
T2:
  1
 / \
2   3

T1:
  1
 / \
2   3
     \
      4
```

If we build the strings for T2 and T1:

preorder T2: "1,2,3" 
preorder T1: "1,2,3,4"
inorder T2: "2,1,3"
inorder T1: "2,1,3,4"

The T2 strings are substrings of T1, so using the substring matching method described above, we should conclude T2 is a subtree of T1.

However, T2 by definition shouldn't be a subtree of T1 since it doesn't have all the descendants of T1's root node.

There is a related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287980/checking-subtrees-using-preorder-and-inorder-strings), which seems to conclude the method is correct.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very interesting question. You seem to be correct. I suppose the issue that you mention arises due to different definitions of subtree in [math (graph theory)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subtree.html) and computer science. In graph theory T2 is a proper subtree of T1.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you got this from the book "Cracking the Coding Interview", the author also mentions that to distinguish between nodes with the same values, one should also print out the null values.

This would also solve your problem with the definition of a subtree (which is correct as also described in the book)

preorder T2: "1, 2, null, null, 3, null, null" 
preorder T1: "1, 2, null, null, 3, null, 4, null, null"
inorder T2: "null, 2, null, 1, null, 3, null"
inorder T1: "null, 2, null, 1, null, 3, null, 4, null"

As you can see, T2 is not a subtree of T1

Answer (score 0):

The definition of sub-tree of a tree should be same as the definition of sub-string of a string. Think of it like this:
1. sub-string has begins-with, contains and ends-with.
2. Tree should also have the same definition but generalized to suit the Tree data structure.
3. The generalization is from 1 dimensional for string to 2 dimensional for tree.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the same book and doubted its solution as well.  I came up with another counter-example that doesn't fall into the potential interpretation that user icepack mentions (of a subtree not necessarily needing all the descendents).

Consider the following trees

```
T2:
  B
 / \
A   C

T1:
    C
   / \
  B   C
 /
A
```

preorder T2: 'BAC'
preorder T1: 'CBAC'
inorder T2: 'ABC'
inorder T1: 'ABCC'

Again, the T2 strings are substrings of their T1 counterparts and yet T2 is in no way a subtree of T1.  Perhaps in the author had ruled out duplicates and specifically mentioned his definition of subtree it could be right, but leaving out that information leaves us with no choice but to consider it an incorrect solution.

Comment: You can't reuse `C` like that, that's not how the theory works.

Comment: I'm not sure what theory you're referring to.  I just noticed that the book makes no mention of the trees having no duplicate values (the book is very explicit in designating when it's referring to binary search trees as opposed to general binary trees .. this case was not a binary search tree).

Comment: "one could build string representations for T2 and T1 using pre-order and in-order traversals, and if T2 strings are substrings of T1 strings, T2 is a subtree of T1."  This theory could only be correct if each node has an unique character.  If you need more characters you'd also need a method to be explicit about where the beginning of a node name is, such as node names begin with uppercase and all other characters are lowercase.

Comment: Oh, I'm not labeling the nodes, those were intended to be the values of the nodes (maybe I should have used integers), but again the book didn't specify for this problem that there are no duplicates, and so the idea of using the in-order / pre-order string representations to figure out if one is a subtree of the other is incorrect.  That's all I was trying to illustrate with my answer.

Comment: when it says "one could build string representations for T2 and T1 " that means with a representation of each node, not their values.  Obviously using values is absolutely pointless for the reasons you describe in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

---

### First of all

The problem is also from book `<Cracking the coding interview 6th>`, at section: `IX Interview Questions` | `4. Trees and graphs` | `Question 4.10`.

*(It's a great book by `Gayle Laakmann McDowell`, a software engineer from Google, who has interviewed a lot people. )*

---

### Algorithms

- **(A) Search root & match subtree algorithm.**

  **Complexity:**

  - Time

    - `O(n + m*k)`
      Worst, rarely happen.
    - `O(n2 + m2*k2)`
      Average, could be smaller than `O(n + m)` *(from the other algorithm)*, but depends.
  - Space:   `O(lg(m) + lg(n))`
    *(Mainly taken by method stacks of recursive calls.)*

  **Where:**

  - `n`
    It's the size of large tree.
  - `m`
    It's the size of small tree.
  - `k`
    The occurrences that root of small tree found in larger tree.
  - `n2`
    The count of node search in larger tree, before a subtree is found.
    It's between `[1, n]`.
  - `m2`
    The average count matched when a root is found.
    For random input, this should be very small.
  - `k2`
    The occurrences of root searched, before a subtree is found.
- **(B) Traverse both trees to lists respectively, and find sub list.**

  **Complexity:**

  - Time:    `O(n + m)`
  - Space:   `O(n + m))`

  **Where:**

  - `n`
    It's the size of large tree.
  - `m`
    It's the size of small tree.

  **Tips**:

  - Should use `pre-order` traverse, and also need to put null node as a special value to list.
    Otherwise different trees might output the same list.
  - `in-order` traverse won't work.
    Because it might output the same ordered list for different outputs for trees that contains the same elements in different order, even with null node represented with special value.

**Compare 2 algorithms:**

- A use less memory, thus more scalable for very large input.
- A's speed is unsure, but on average it could still be quicker than B.
- B's algorithm is simpler.

---

### Code

*(Following is an implementation in `Java` containing **both** algorithms, with test case.)*

**CheckSubtree.java**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Given 2 binary tree T1 & T2, they are very large, and T1 is much larger than T2.
 * <p>Check whether T2 is a subtree of T1,
 *
 * @author eric
 * @date 2/9/19 1:48 PM
 */
public class CheckSubtree {
    /**
     * Check whether small tree is subtree of large tree, via searching root & match.
     * <p>Return on first match.
     *
     * @param largeTree large tree,
     * @param smallTree small tree,
     * @param <T>
     * @return true if small tree is subtree of large tree, or small tree is empty,
     */
    public static <T extends Comparable> boolean checkViaRootAndMatch(BST<T> largeTree, BST<T> smallTree) {
        if (smallTree.size() == 0) return true; // small tree is empty,

        BST.BSTNode<T> matchNode = searchAndMatch(largeTree.getRoot(), smallTree); // search root & try match,
        return matchNode != null;
    }

    /**
     * Search root, and check whether the subtree there match small tree.
     *
     * @param largeCurrent subtree of large tree,
     * @param smallTree    small tree,
     * @param <T>
     * @return node from large tree that match small tree, or null if not found,
     */
    protected static <T extends Comparable> BST.BSTNode<T> searchAndMatch(BST.BSTNode<T> largeCurrent, BST<T> smallTree) {
        if (largeCurrent == null) return null; // subtree of large is empty,
        T smallRoot = smallTree.getRoot().getValue(); // value of small tree's root,

        if (largeCurrent.getValue().compareTo(smallRoot) == 0) { // found root of small tree,
            if (match(largeCurrent, smallTree)) return largeCurrent; // also match the whole small tree,
        }

        BST.BSTNode<T> leftFoundNode = searchAndMatch(largeCurrent.getLeft(), smallTree); // search in left subtree,
        if (leftFoundNode != null) return leftFoundNode; // match in left subtree of current,

        return searchAndMatch(largeCurrent.getRight(), smallTree); // search in right subtree,
    }

    /**
     * Check whether small tree match at given subtree of large tree.
     *
     * @param largeCurrent subtree of large tree,
     * @param smallTree    small tree,
     * @param <T>
     * @return
     */
    protected static <T extends Comparable> boolean match(BST.BSTNode<T> largeCurrent, BST<T> smallTree) {
        return match(largeCurrent, smallTree.getRoot());
    }

    /**
     * Check whether subtree of small tree match at given subtree of large tree.
     *
     * @param largeCurrent subtree of large tree,
     * @param smallCurrent subtree of small tree,
     * @param <T>
     * @return true if subtree of small is subtree of large, or subtree of small is empty,
     */
    protected static <T extends Comparable> boolean match(BST.BSTNode<T> largeCurrent, BST.BSTNode<T> smallCurrent) {
        if (smallCurrent == null) return true; // smaller reach leaf,
        if (largeCurrent == null) return false; // larger is empty, while smaller is not,

        if (largeCurrent.getValue().compareTo(smallCurrent.getValue()) != 0)
            return false; // current value is different,

        if (!match(largeCurrent.getLeft(), smallCurrent.getLeft())) return false; // check whether left subtree match,
        return match(largeCurrent.getRight(), smallCurrent.getRight()); // check whether right subtree match,
    }

    // traverse both tree and generate a list representation, then check whether the small list is sub list of large list,

    /**
     * Check whether small tree is subtree of large tree, via traverse tree to list & find sublist. Use given null value.
     * <p>Return on first match.
     *
     * @param largeTree
     * @param smallTree
     * @param <T>
     * @return
     */
    public static <T extends Comparable> boolean checkViaTraverseAndSublist(BST<T> largeTree, BST<T> smallTree) {
        return checkViaTraverseAndSublist(largeTree, smallTree, null);
    }

    /**
     * Check whether small tree is subtree of large tree, via traverse tree to list & find sublist. Use given special value.
     * <p>Return on first match.
     *
     * @param largeTree
     * @param smallTree
     * @param special   special value to represent value of null node in tree,
     * @param <T>
     * @return
     */
    public static <T extends Comparable> boolean checkViaTraverseAndSublist(BST<T> largeTree, BST<T> smallTree, T special) {
        if (smallTree.size() == 0) return true; // small tree is empty,

        // tree to list,
        List<T> largeList = treeToList(largeTree, special);
        List<T> smallList = treeToList(smallTree, special);
        // System.out.printf("large list: %s\n", largeList);
        // System.out.printf("small list: %s\n", smallList);

        int idx = Collections.lastIndexOfSubList(largeList, smallList); // find sublist,
        return idx >= 0;
    }

    /**
     * Traverse tree and add nodes to list, with pre-order, use special value to represent null node.
     *
     * @param tree
     * @param special special value to represent value of null node in tree,
     * @param <T>
     * @return
     */
    protected static <T extends Comparable> List<T> treeToList(BST<T> tree, T special) {
        List<T> list = new LinkedList<>();
        treeToList(tree.getRoot(), special, list);
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Traverse subtree and add nodes to list, with pre-order, use special value to represent null node.
     *
     * @param current
     * @param special special value to represent value of null node in tree,
     * @param list
     * @param <T>
     */
    protected static <T extends Comparable> void treeToList(BST.BSTNode<T> current, T special, List<T> list) {
        if (current == null) {
            list.add(special); // represent null with special value,
            return;
        }

        list.add(current.getValue()); // current,
        treeToList(current.getLeft(), special, list); // left subtree,
        treeToList(current.getRight(), special, list); // right subtree,
    }
}
```

**CheckSubtreeTest.java**
*(unit test, via `TestNG`)*

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * CheckSubtree test.
 *
 * @author eric
 * @date 2/9/19 4:18 PM
 */
public class CheckSubtreeTest {
    private int n = 10;

    // trees, via minimal BST,
    private BST<Integer> largeTree; // large tree,

    private BST<Integer> smallTree; // small tree, subtree of large tree,
    private BST<Integer> smallTree2; // small tree, not subtree of large tree,

    private BST<Integer> emptyTree; // empty tree,

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init() {
        // init - large tree,
        largeTree = CreateMinimalBST.createRangeNum(0, n);

        // init - small tree,
        smallTree = CreateMinimalBST.createRangeNum(8, 10);
        smallTree2 = CreateMinimalBST.createRangeNum(2, 5);

        // init empty BST,
        emptyTree = new BST<>();
    }

    // checkViaRootAndMatch(),
    @Test
    public void testViaRootAndMatch() {
        Assert.assertTrue(CheckSubtree.checkViaRootAndMatch(largeTree, smallTree)); // subtree,
        Assert.assertFalse(CheckSubtree.checkViaRootAndMatch(largeTree, smallTree2)); // not subtree,
        Assert.assertFalse(CheckSubtree.checkViaRootAndMatch(smallTree, largeTree)); // not subtree,

        // empty tree,
        Assert.assertTrue(CheckSubtree.checkViaRootAndMatch(largeTree, emptyTree));
        Assert.assertTrue(CheckSubtree.checkViaRootAndMatch(smallTree, emptyTree));
        Assert.assertTrue(CheckSubtree.checkViaRootAndMatch(emptyTree, emptyTree));
    }

    // checkViaTraverseAndSublist(),
    @Test
    public void testViaTraverseAndSublist() {
        // Integer special = null;
        // Integer special = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Assert.assertTrue(CheckSubtree.checkViaTraverseAndSublist(largeTree, smallTree)); // subtree,
        Assert.assertFalse(CheckSubtree.checkViaTraverseAndSublist(largeTree, smallTree2)); // not subtree,
        Assert.assertFalse(CheckSubtree.checkViaTraverseAndSublist(smallTree, largeTree)); // not subtree,

        // empty tree,
        Assert.assertTrue(CheckSubtree.checkViaTraverseAndSublist(largeTree, emptyTree));
        Assert.assertTrue(CheckSubtree.checkViaTraverseAndSublist(smallTree, emptyTree));
        Assert.assertTrue(CheckSubtree.checkViaTraverseAndSublist(emptyTree, emptyTree));
    }
}
```

All test cases would pass.

**Tips:**

- `BST` is a simple binary tree impl.
- `BST.BSTNode` is `BST`'s node.
- `CreateMinimalBST` is a tool that help to build a binary search tree of minimal height.

Answer (score -3):

Na...This approach is not correct.Because, different trees can have same traversal . For instance here in the given example, the tree is

```
         26
        /   \
      10     3
    /    \     \
  4      6      3
   \
    30
```

and the candidate subtrees are

```
10
/ \
4 6
\
30
```

and

```
30
/ \
4 10
\
6
```

have the same inorder traversal as 4,30,10,6
but the second one isn't subtree

Comment: The in-order traversal of the last tree isn't 4,30,10,6.
It is 4,6,30,10