# Why is inorder and preorder traversal useful for creating an algorithm to decide if T2 is a subtree of T1

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I'm looking at an interview book and the question is:

> You have two very large binary trees: `T1`, with millions of nodes, and
>   `T2`, with hundreds of nodes. Create an algorithm to decide if `T2` is a
>   subtree of `T1`.

The authors mentions this as a possible solution:

> Note that the problem here specifies that `T1` has millions of
>   nodes—this means that we should be careful of how much space we use.
>   Let’s say, for example, `T1` has 10 million nodes—this means that the
>   data alone is about `40 mb`. **We could create a string representing the
>   inorder and preorder traversals**. If `T2`’s preorder traversal is a
>   substring of `T1`’s preorder traversal, and `T2`’s inorder traversal is a
>   substring of `T1`’s inorder traversal, then `T2` is a substring of `T1`.

I'm not quite sure the logic behind as to why if these are true:

- `T2-preorder-traversal-string` is a substring of `T1-preorder-traversal-string`
- `T2-inorder-traversal-string` is a substring of `T1-inorder-traversal-string`

That `T2` must be a substring (although I assume the author means subtree) of `T1`.  Can I get an explanation to this logic?

**EDIT**:  User *BartoszMarcinkowski* brings up a good point.  Assume both trees have no duplicate nodes.

Comment: Assuming you got this question from Cracking the Coding interview, the author actually does mention that the trees can have duplicate nodes, and even shows an example of it. The way she resolved is by also printing the null values for leave nodes as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is not true. Consider:

```
T2:

  2
 / \
1   3

inorder 123 preorder 213
```

and

```
T1:

      0
     / \
    3   3
   / \ 
  1   1
 / \ 
0   2


inorder 0123103 preorder 0310213
```

`123` is substring of `0123103`, `213` is substring of `0310213`, but T2 is not subtree of T1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure one of the constraints is no duplicate nodes.

Comment: Then it would be quite obvious :)

Comment: I would also expect this assumption, but +1 for a good counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter-example to the method.

Consider the tree `T1`:

```
  B
 / \
A   D
   / \
  C   E
       \
        F
```

And the sub-tree `T2`:

```
  D
 / \
C   E
```

The relevant traversals are:

- `T1` pre-order: `BADCEF`
- `T2` pre-order: `DCE`
- `T1` in-order: `ABCDEF`
- `T2` in-order: `CDE`

While `DCE` is in `BADCEF` and `CDE` is in `ABCDEF`, `T2` is not actually a sub-tree of `T1`. The author's definition of sub-tree must have been different or it was just a mistake.

Related question: [Determine if a binary tree is subtree of another binary tree using pre-order and in-order strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381294/determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-subtree-of-another-binary-tree-using-pre-order-and)

Comment: Why don't we care about post-order though?  Also, your `BADCEF` counter example doesn't make sense..maybe I'm not seeing something

Comment: What's your definition for subtree?

Answer (score 1):

Important assumption is that the tree has **unique keys**.

Now, note that `preorder-traversal-string` and `inorder-traversal-string` uniquely identify a binary tree.

**Scatch of the proof:**

Let `T` be a tree.

- First object in `preorder-traversal-string(T)` is the root.
- Find it in the in the `inorder-traversal-string(T)` - everything on left of that element is your left subtree `L`, let's call this substring `inorder-traversal-string(L)`. Everything on right is your right subtree `R`.

Now, let's focus on the left subtree `L`.

- Clearly all subtrees are separated (they don't mix) in both strings. They are represented as consecutive objects. The only problem is that a priori we don't know where `preorder-traversal-string(L)` ends in `preorder-traversal-string(T)`.
- Note that strings `inorder-traversal-string(L)` and `preorder-traversal-string(L)` have the same length. This gives as the place where to cut.
- Now you have a subtree described as substrings `inorder-traversal-string(L)` and `preorder-traversal-string(L)` so you can repeat the procedure till the end.

Following those steps (inefficient but it is just for the proof) for all subtrees you will uniquely build the tree.

Thus, all subtrees of `T1` are described uniquely by corresponding `inorder-traversal-string` and `preorder-traversal-string`.